# Water Pollutant or Contaminant Dataset

Tags: data-request

I am looking for any water dataset for pollutant or contaminant in water (like mercury, arsenic, etc) and I need the dataset include data of ph, do, ec, orp, and temperature as well. Where I can find those things?
I haven't found a relevant dataset.

Comment: Quandl has some datasets on organic water pollutant (BOD) emissions in a few countries. See https://www.quandl.com/data/WWDI?keyword=water%20pollutant. Would something like this help? [Disclosure: I work for Quandl]

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain some data about water quality and contaminant from USGS Water Quality databases:

http://waterdata.usgs.gov/nwis/qw
http://www.waterqualitydata.us/).

It contains many water quality characteristics for the US territory - these are large and diverse data sets. If you're not familiar with the formats & databases, consider paying someone to do the data wra